# Microsoft DBMS on-the-fly aggregation

Tags: database, aggregation, on-the-fly

Some time ago i was reading an article about new MS DBMS technology. It's some kind of OLAP but on the fly. This technology can bind to data flows and then provide a real time aggregation. So the question is "what is it's name?". I need such a technology now but can't remember it's name... Or maybe there are some similar technologies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is no more actual...

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to [PopFly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PopFly)?  [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)? [Reactive LINQ](http://reactivelinq.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's not exactly what i need. It was very interesting to know about Reactive LINQ. Seems very useful and i'll use it for another task.
The technology i'm asking about is itself DBMS server software (or maybe an extension to MS SQL Server) it monitors data flows and re-compute aggregated values we need. Maybe it works in similar to Reactive LINQ way... i can't remember... And maybe it's still not released...

Answer (score 1):

What about this site:

(M Language): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee460940.aspx

or this one:

(Quadrant): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee477952.aspx

Regards.

Comment: Thank you. Both links are interesting but no relation with what i'm looking for =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you was reading about powerpivot